# Android - Long Click on RecyclerView item and ContextMenu

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, contextmenu

**Problem:** Cannot display a context menu showing a "delete" option" when longclicking on an item within a recyclerview

**Result expected:** see image below

I'm almost there, but I'm missing something to make the contextMenu displayed on a longClick.

Here is what I put in the viewHolder. I don't know what I should add and where to display the context menu in the onLongClick event.

I skipped some lines of code and kept the ones relevant to my question.

Thanks a lot for your assistance,

**My interface to handle both types of clicks**

```
public interface OnItemClickListener{
    void onItemClick(int position);
}

public interface OnItemLongClickListener{
    void onItemLongClick(int position);
}
```

**Viewholder code**

```
public void bindLongClick(final int position, final OnItemLongClickListener onItemLongClickListener) {
        itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                onItemLongClickListener.onItemLongClick(position);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu contextMenu, View view, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo contextMenuInfo){
            //menuInfo is null
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "grrr");
        contextMenu.setHeaderTitle("Select The Action");
        contextMenu.add(0, view.getId(), 0, "Supprimer");//groupId, itemId, order, title
    }
```

**Adapter code**

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CityListViewholder holder, int position) {
        holder.cityName.setText(cityArrayList.get(position).getCityName());
        holder.bindClick(position, onItemClickListener);
        holder.bindLongClick(position, onItemLongClickListener);
    }
```

**Then, in the activity - I skipped what is not relevant for my question**

```
mCityListAdapter = new CityListAdapter(mContext, cityArrayList, new CityListAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int position) {
                mPager.setCurrentItem(position);
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            }
        }, new CityListAdapter.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemLongClick(int position) {
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Position "+position);
            }
        });

        registerForContextMenu(mRecyclerView);
```

[image: Expected result]

Comment: Sorry, seems I didn't fully get it? Do you want to show popup, when you long clicking on item?

Comment: Thanks Michael, I updated my question adding an illustration of what I'm expecting as well as a better description of my problem on top of the question.

Comment: @millinet Show Context menu in Long Click. By seeing your code you didnot implemented anything in LongClick

Comment: @JagjitSingh I know, this is what I'm missing. It might be easy, but I can't figure out how to "call/display" it.

Comment: Should I put "onCreateContextMenu(...);" within the long click? Thanks

Comment: you can find the answer in stackoverflow documentation here:  http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/169/recyclerview#t=201607270859508946896,   find popup menu with recyclerview

Comment: here is the proper link:   http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/169/recyclerview/14542/popup-memu-with-recyclerview#t=2016072709040264992

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What you need there is to show Dialog with list inside. Like that:

```
    itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            final CharSequence[] items = {"Supprimer", "etc", "etc1"};

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

            builder.setTitle("Select The Action");
            builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                }
            });
            builder.show();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: So no need to registerContextMenu and associated methods? This solution might do the trick indeed even if I wanted to experiment the context menu.

Comment: No need, at least last time I was working with context menu something like 3 years ago,  and I don't think that it's useful.

Comment: I finally chose your solution which is just the easiest way to implement what I wanted to do. Thanks!

Comment: @Divers Perfect Solution, Small and Optimised. Thanks :)

Comment: How do you get the selected item in the RecyclerView?

Answer (score 2):

Accepted answer isn't technically "the answer", it is rather a clever workaround since it creates an `AlertDialog` instead of a `ContextMenu` as requested by the OP, it does "solve the requirement" but it does not create a `ContextMenu`.

## This is the shortest implementation I found:

## In Activity, override as usual:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    menu.add("do this");
    menu.add("do that");
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getTitle().equals("do this") {
        // do whatever this...
    }
    else if (item.getTitle().equals("do that") {
        // do whatever that...
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

## In RecyclerView's item ViewHolder:

```
private class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ...
    private ItemViewHolder(@NonNull View pItemView) {
        super(pItemView);
        pItemView.setLongClickable(true); // <-- make long clickable
        ...
    }
}
```

## In Activity onCreate:

```
registerForContextMenu(myRecyclerView);
```

Comment: Downvoted because there is no logic for getting which item has been long clicked! ContextMenu is in Activity Context while LongClick is in Adapter

Comment: Its right there in the .onContextItemSelected() event handler above - its pretty clear as day. Calling .registerForContextMenu() on the activity registers the RecyclerView w/ the event handler defined above. Event handler does not have to be inside the Adapter, in fact it could be in a separate class altogether. FYI this is also well tested code, sample taken from one of the apps in production.

Comment: @AlexVPerl Right, but if we have a recycler of people, how do we get the name of the person who was long clicked in onContextItemSelected()?

Answer (score 0):

Edit 1: To specifically show dialog, use

```
 openContextMenu(v);
```

where v refers to the View. and

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu,menu);
}
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  int id = item.getItemId();
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

The code in `context_menu` file in Menu folder should look like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/item"
        android:orderInCategory="200"
        android:title="Item"
        android:icon="@drawable/faq"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        ></item>
</menu>
```

In the past, I was too having some problems with RecyclerView's `onClickListener` and `onLongClickListener`. So here's the one I am using:

```
public class ItemClickSupport {
    private final RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;
    private OnItemLongClickListener mOnItemLongClickListener;
    private View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mOnItemClickListener != null) {
                RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = mRecyclerView.getChildViewHolder(v);
                mOnItemClickListener.onItemClicked(mRecyclerView, holder.getAdapterPosition(), v);
            }
        }
    };
    private View.OnLongClickListener mOnLongClickListener = new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            if (mOnItemLongClickListener != null) {
                RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = mRecyclerView.getChildViewHolder(v);
                return mOnItemLongClickListener.onItemLongClicked(mRecyclerView, holder.getAdapterPosition(), v);
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
    private RecyclerView.OnChildAttachStateChangeListener mAttachListener
            = new RecyclerView.OnChildAttachStateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildViewAttachedToWindow(View view) {
            if (mOnItemClickListener != null) {
                view.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
            }
            if (mOnItemLongClickListener != null) {
                view.setOnLongClickListener(mOnLongClickListener);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildViewDetachedFromWindow(View view) {

        }
    };

    private ItemClickSupport(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        mRecyclerView = recyclerView;
        mRecyclerView.setTag(R.id.item_click_support, this);
        mRecyclerView.addOnChildAttachStateChangeListener(mAttachListener);
    }

    public static ItemClickSupport addTo(RecyclerView view) {
        ItemClickSupport support = (ItemClickSupport) view.getTag(R.id.item_click_support);
        if (support == null) {
            support = new ItemClickSupport(view);
        }
        return support;
    }

    public static ItemClickSupport removeFrom(RecyclerView view) {
        ItemClickSupport support = (ItemClickSupport) view.getTag(R.id.item_click_support);
        if (support != null) {
            support.detach(view);
        }
        return support;
    }

    public ItemClickSupport setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mOnItemClickListener = listener;
        return this;
    }

    public ItemClickSupport setOnItemLongClickListener(OnItemLongClickListener listener) {
        mOnItemLongClickListener = listener;
        return this;
    }

    private void detach(RecyclerView view) {
        view.removeOnChildAttachStateChangeListener(mAttachListener);
        view.setTag(R.id.item_click_support, null);
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {

        void onItemClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v);
    }

    public interface OnItemLongClickListener {

        boolean onItemLongClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v);
    }
}
```

and then in the activity, use the following:

```
ItemClickSupport.addTo(recyclerView).setOnItemLongClickListener(new ItemClickSupport.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v) {

                return true;
            }
    });
```

Use `position`to specify item. Hope it helps!